# Progress Providex database openquery SQL error

Tags: sql-server, openedge, openquery, progress-db

I get this error when I do a openquery select to a linked server using an providex odbc driver. The database I am trying to connect to is built on Progress.

Cannot get the current row value of column "[MSDASQL].IVD_PRICE" from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "FCEU". Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the data type used by the provider.

Is there a work around for this? I do not have access to the server I am trying to query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Progress database implements **all** datatypes as variable length.  The "format" is just a suggestion for default display purposes.  Progress applications routinely ignore that suggestion and "over-stuff" fields.

This gives most SQL clients hissy fits.

The cure depends on the version of Progress/OpenEdge.

All versions of Progress starting with version 9 support a utility called "dbtool" which will scan the db and adjust the "SQL-WIDTH" attribute for any fields that have been over-stuffed.  You must run this on the server.  (Or convince the DBA to do it.)

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P24496

This is a very common, routine procedure for Progress databases.

You can also use the -checkwidth parameter to keep these things from happening -- but in your case the horse is already out of the barn and it might break the application.  So it probably isn't useful to you right now.

Starting with OpenEdge 11.5 there are new features to automatically handle width violations when a SQL client connects:

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-enable-Authorized-Data-Truncation-in-a-JDBC-or-ODBC-connection